# How does $dV=2\pi R^2t \sin \theta\, d\theta$ come?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, volume, classical-mechanics

How does $dV=2\pi R^2 t \sin \theta\, d\theta$ come?

From the figure shown in the screenshot, How do I prove $dV=2\pi R^2 t \sin \theta \,d\theta$?

[image]

**My Attempt**
[image]

Comment: You can seen better this link-image: https://slideplayer.com/slide/14460862/90/images/26/Spherical+mass+distributions.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are differentials. We are allowed to multiply the elemental volumes just as for rectangular / cuboid blocks. Cone differential area with $ds$ along local cone tangent

$$dA= 2\pi r ds = (2\pi R \sin \theta) R d\theta$$

For constant shell thickness

$$ dV = t\cdot dA$$

The sphere has this special property..

The truncated spherical segment volume equals segment height $h$ times $2 \pi R$ i.e., should be multiplied by $ R(\cos \theta_2-\cos \theta_2)=h,$

For differential volume next multiply by shell thickness $t$.

First question: Area by definition of a curvilinear surface is the rate at which the  Volume is increasing... If you differentiate $\frac43 \pi R^3$ with respect to $R$ you get the area $ 4 \pi R^2.$

Second question  $ dV_{inside\;of\;ball}= \pi r^2 dz$ is true for the volume inside a soccer ball for whereas $dV_{thick\;shell\;of\;ball\;}=t\cdot dA. $

Comment: I understood the formula of $dA$. How does $dV=t \cdot dA$ come?

Comment: $dA$ is the lateral surface area. Right? Usually, Volume =Base * Height. Right?

Comment: I replied in my answer. Like volume of an orange fruit and and its outer peel.

Comment: Now, I got it. But in the figure they have show only sphere. So, I confused. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate it with a Jacobian determinant or differential forms, but the diagram allows a simpler argument. The shaded ring has circumference $2\pi R\sin\theta$, which we multiply by the width and thickness to get the stated result.

Comment: from where does this $t$ come from?

Comment: I know $2\pi R \sin \theta . Rd\theta$ yeald the surface area of the shaded region.

Comment: @Unknownx Which we then multiply by "the thickness $t$" mentioned in the text. By the way, we indicate multiplication with $\cdot$ (`\cdot`), not $.$.

Comment: I am confused. How do we find the volume? Base area* Height. Right?

Comment: Here, Circumference =$2\pi R\sin\theta$. This thing I understood, If I multiplied with $ds=Rd\theta$, we get the area of the shaded region. What is thickness here? The distance between the disk on the top and bottom of the slice. Right?@J.G.